# Find a formula for calculate $\prod_{n=0}^N(a^n + b)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, products, infinite-product

I have an expression, in which I am looking for a formula to calculate

$$ \prod_{n=0}^N (a^n +b)$$

as a summation. Is there a general name for this type of formula? Or a relevant approach to find partial products such as this one?

Comment: You can try splitting it and remembering $\prod_{n=0}^N a^n = a^{\sum_{n=0}^N}n$

Comment: That is a useful idea, I'm not sure what you refer to as "splitting it" however. Can you elaborate a little? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Gaussian binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient), also known as the q-analogs of the binomial coefficient, gives a representation of: $$ \prod_{n=0}^{N} (a^n + b) = b^{N+1} \: \left(-\frac{1}{b}; \: a \right)_{N+1} = b^{N+1} \: \sum_{j=0}^{N+1} {{N+1} \brack {j}}_a \: \left( \frac{1}{b}\right)^j a^{\binom{j}{2}} $$ Though I think that sum would be much more computationally expensive than just running the product through.